# Problems when creating Compass project (EACCES on line ["891"])

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass

I am having problems when creating a new compass project (Windows 7). I get this:

```
C:\>compass create a
   create config.rb
Errno::EACCES on line ["891"] of C: Permission denied - (C:/a/config.rb20140321-6828-1g0ytlc, C:/a/config.rb)
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

I have tried to start cmd with "Run as administrator", I have tried to delete compass, sass and ruby, and reinstalled without any luck. Anyone else having problems or know a solution to this irritating problem?

Comment: I also found out that I even can't compile existing sass prosjects. This happend after I updated compass and sass...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was using the latest version (21.03.2014) of compass v.0.12.4...
Downgraded to v.0.12.2 everything worked fine!

Looks like a bug?

To downgrade:

```
$ gem uninstall compass 
$ gem uninstall sass 
$ gem install compass -v 0.12.2 
$ gem install sass -v <rev>
```

Comment: I spent a whole day trying to figure what is the problem I was frustrated, I didn't know what to do? I re-installed ruby many times even I tried on my virtual Linux but it didn't work. until I installed compass v 0.12.3 and sass v. 3.2.14

Comment: 0.12.3 was the way to go for me as well. How weird that I've been spending many hours today looking for a solution, and just like that the answer pops up on stack overflow. Thanks guys!

Comment: I confirm 0.12.3 worked for me as well. 0.12.2 gave me a bunch of errors thought

Comment: Same issue here. I can confirm that Compass 0.12.3 and SASS 3.2.14 worked on Win7, following the steps above

Answer (score 0):

Please update to Sass 3.2.18 and let me know if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this linked to

[Compass/Sass writing files with "No Access" permissions for Everyone group on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581861/compass-sass-writing-files-with-no-access-permissions-for-everyone-group-on-os/22583705#22583705)?

*If so*, updating to 3.2.18 hasn't made a difference.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved in Compass version 0.12.5
https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/1618