# Getting error EACCES when I try to use compass

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass

I was using sass and compass. But now I can't compile or create new project. This started to happen when I tried to install susy. But susy couldn't work because of sass version. I uninstalled susy and tried again, and no success. I reinstalled ruby, compass and again no success.

I keep getting this message when i try compass watch:

```
Errno::EACCES on line["891"] C: permission denied (D:/aptana/training/css/styles.css20140321-4156-104zael, D:/aptana/training/styles.css)
```

And when I go compass create:

```
Errno::EACCES on line["891"] C: permission denied (D:/aptana/example/config.rb20140321-1044pvb7un, D:/aptana/example/config.rb)
```

Can anyone help me everything was fine till now. I haven't done anything differently from the first time i installed ruby sass and compass.

Comment: See this answer from 10 hours ago:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22559284/problems-when-creating-compass-project-eacces-on-line-891

Comment: Yes I have managed to fix it myself it is compatibility issue. I now have sass 3.2.17, compass 0.12.3 and susy 1.0.8 and it's working. We have to wait for new compass to be able to work with susy 2. Or maybe there is another trick to do this.