# Compass/Sass writing files with "No Access" permissions for Everyone group on OSX

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I'm using Sass and Compass (on osx) and using "compass watch" to compile my .scss files. The compilation runs OK, in that the .css files are created with the correct content. However, looking at the permissions shows that the file is written with the "Everyone" group as having "No Access" resulting in the css not appearing on the page. When I correct the permissions manually all is well again, but any subsequent saves result in compass overwriting the file with "No access" permissions again.

I'm not sure whether the problem here is with my config.rb (but I don't think so), or the permissions within the sass subdirectories. I've deleted .sass-cache and repeated the setup. How does compass derive its write permissions?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not a solution, the test for whether Compass, Sass, directory permissions were at fault was to create a new directory entirely outside of the project structure and run the following in the terminal for that project

```
compass create
compass watch
```

I then checked whether the css files produced had Read permissions.

In my case, they had the expected Read permissions (Everyone: read) so I concluded that it was something related to the directory permission of the original project. As a fix I recreated the directory structure in another location, copied over the files unrelated to CSS/SASS and then began again with compass create, compass watch to generate the css.

I don't believe this was related to the current Sass issue

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a known issue with a Sass utility as of Compass 0.12.4: https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/1615#issuecomment-38332287

The Sass fixes are present in the most recent version, but I think we're going to have to wait for Compass 0.12.5.

Comment: Thanks for that link Matt. I still don't get readable files using gem install sass --version "~> 3.2.18" posted an hour ago by chriseppstein . I've also tried it following {gem update --system, gem update, bundle install, compass clean}

Comment: ...I think I just fully understood your second paragraph. Functionally, and conceptually, I no longer separate Sass and Compass but are you saying that Chris Eppstein's fix relies on Compass being updated?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. I'm very new to these tools and heard many conflicting reports; I just transitioned away from Compass trying multiple combinations of reverted versions.

Answer (score 0):

RVM worked as a solution for me.

I was having the same exact problem using the native Ruby install on OS X Mavericks.  Like you, I tried the method of creating an independent test compass project outside of the working project directory where I originally encountered this same issue.  Compass still generated css files inaccessible to all others.

The solution for me was to install RVM and Ruby v.2.1.1.  Then I installed Compass the normal way and didn't even need to do so with sudo.

This is just an uneducated guess but maybe installing and running gems through the native Ruby either just doesn't jive with the non-system user, or version 2.0.0 has permissions issues with Compass 0.12.4.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ben. It was convenient that I'd just started the project. Will try playing around with RVM and ruby as you suggest if it occurs again.